# Format text as user inputs in a contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I'm attempting to make a page that allows users to input text and it will automatically format the input -- as in a screenplay format (similar to Amazon's StoryWriter).

So far I can check for text with ":contains('example text')" and add/remove classes to it. The problem is that all of the following p tags inherit that class.

My solution so far is to use .next() to remove the class I added, but that is limited since there might be need for a line break in the script (in dialogue for instance) and that will remove the dialogue class.

```
$('.content').on('input', function() {
    $("p.input:contains('INT.')").addClass("high").next(".input").removeClass("high");
    $("p.input:contains('EXT.')").addClass("high").next(".input").removeClass("high");
});
```

I can't get || to work in the :contains parameter either, but that's the least of my issues.

I have a [JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o0c1rq5L/)

I've worked on this for a while now, and if I could change only the node that contains the text (INT. or EXT. in this example) and leaves the rest alone that would work and I could apply it to the rest of the script.

Any help would be appreciated, I'm new to the stackoverflow so thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SO, @cPatton! Could you elaborate a bit what you're trying to achieve? At least I'm having a hard time getting my head around this.

Comment: Do you only want one of the input sections `(p.input)` to be highlighted at any one time?

Comment: Sorry for my delay in answering your questions (work and stuff). I appreciate the interest in answering.  @jsruok I'm trying to write with a  movie script format in a contenteditable div (with each line after enter is pressed wrapped in p tags). Scene headings (all caps), narrative descriptions, and dialogue blocks all have different styles.  I'm trying to allow the user to type something indicative of the style (ie. INT. or EXT. for scene headings) to apply that style for margins and text transforms (uppercase for instance). The problem is when I apply the style, it changes all p tags after.

Comment: @Stormblessed Since it could be a lengthy script, there will be several instances of the various classes I'm trying to add.

Comment: See my answer. Any questions, please ask :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the comments in the code below for an explanation of what's going on.

[Fiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/o0c1rq5L/1/)

**JQuery**

```
var main = function(){

  var content = $('.content');

  content.on('input', function() {
    $("p.input").each(function() {
      //Get the html content for the current p input.
      var text = $(this).html();
      //indexOf will return a positive value if "INT." or "EXT." exists in the html
      if (text.indexOf('INT.') !== -1 || text.indexOf('EXT.') !== -1) {
        $(this).addClass('high');
      }
      //You could include additional "if else" blocks to check and apply different conditions
      else { //The required text does not exist, so remove the class for the current input
        $(this).removeClass('high');
      }
    });
  });
};//main close

$(document).ready(main);
```